How do I evaluate $\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{1 + \alpha t^2} \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}\alpha$?
How would I evaluate the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{1 + \alpha t^2}\, \mathrm{d}t \, \mathrm{d}\alpha?
$$

Don't use picure try to write your question

You can use \int_0^1\int_0^\infty to get $$\int_0^1\int_0^\infty$$

In what context did you come up with this integral? What techniques do you know? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? You have to put effort into asking your question if you intend for people in this community to put effort into answering it! Read this.
